# Angular-Strap Alerts: Unable to capture when alert.hide() triggers

Tags: angularjs, alert, angular-strap

I am trying to implement an automatic alert into my AngularJS application using Angular-Strap and the `$alert` service.  So far so good, however, I am left with an issue I can't seem to resolve.

Is there a way I can I set a callback to capture when the `$alert` is hidden either using the `duration` property or the `alert.hide()` command?  I want to run a function when the alert goes into a hidden state.

My code snippets looks like this:

```
var alertContent = '';


        // Define the critical alert
        var criticalAlert = $alert({
                            templateUrl: 'templates/critical.alert.tpl.html',  
                            title: ' Critical Alert Detected!', 
                            content: alertContent, 
                            container: 'body', 
                            type: 'danger', 
                            dismissable: false, 
                            duration: '20', 
                            show: false
                        });
```

...

```
alertContent = 'Foo Bar!';
```

...

```
criticalAlert.$promise.then(criticalAlert.hide);
```

...

```
$scope.$on('alert.hide', function() {
            console.log('Alert Hidden');
        });
```

Comment: I have found the right solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the `$promise`, you can pass your own function, eg:

```
criticalAlert.$promise.then(function(){criticalAlert.hide();console.log('Alert Hidden'); })
```

More about `$promise` [anglular $q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

**UPDATE**

You can use `$watch`.

Of course, it's not a nice solution, but the best I found. At least, it works!

```
var alert = $alert({
  title: ' Critical Alert Detected!',
  content: 'its Alert!',
  container: 'body',
  type: 'danger',
  dismissable: false,
  duration: '5',
  show: false,
});
$scope.$watch(function(){return alert.$isShown;},function(val){
  if(val===true)
    console.log('alert opened',val);
  else
    console.log('alert closed',val);
});
alert.$promise.then(alert.show);
```

**UPDATED 2**

We can use `event` of angular.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/xLomzp7g/).

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $alert) {
$scope.alert = $alert({
  title: ' Critical Alert Detected!',
  content: 'its Alert!',
  container: '#divForAlert',
  type: 'danger',
  dismissable: false,
  duration: '5',
  show: false,
  prefixEvent:"mymodal",
});
$scope.alert.$promise.then(function() {
  $scope.alert.show();
});
$scope.$root.$on('mymodal.hide.before', function(event) {
  console.log('hide before',event);
});
 $scope.$root.$on('mymodal.hide', function(alert) {
  console.log('hide',alert);
});});
```

And some **important** html

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
<h3>
  ExampleController
</h3>
<form name="ExampleForm" id="ExampleForm">
  <div id="divForAlert">

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What about when it auto closes due to the duration property?

Comment: Also, is there a way I can capture .hide.before()?

Comment: I read that when you close the `modal` event `hide.before` occurs. But for some reason `$scope.$on('modal.hide.before',function(){})` not work.